# Reading GLB files in JSZip

Tags: javascript, three.js, jszip

How would I read a glb file using JSZip

The only thing Ican think of is using this method.

```
 zip.file("hello.txt").async("string");
```

Maybe converting the string into Base64 But I don't know.

Comment: You're on the right track, async returns a promise, what are you doing with it?

Comment: rendering it using three.js

Comment: Use `async("blob")` then, assuming you're actually working with `*.glb` files

Comment: did you have any luck with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a full example for you:

```js
const JSZip = require("jszip");
const zip = new JSZip();

zip.loadAsync(glbFilePath)
  .then(() => {
    return zip.file("yourmodel.glb").async("blob");
  })
  .then((fileData) => {
    var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();

    // load the GLB file
    loader.load(fileData, function (gltf) {
        var model = gltf.scene;
        
        // add the model to your scene
    });
  });
```

Comment: How do I use Josip in the web?

Comment: Probably best suited in another question. If this has helped you don’t forget to mark it and I’ll try to help you in your next question

Comment: Can you please add the code to make a new scene with the canvas and incorporating the glb code. the code I wrote for basic shapes is to complicated. Thanks!

Comment: Surpassing "complicated"  is what makes you a better developer :)